# Integrating $\int_{-\infty}^0e^x\sin(x)dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I ask if anyone could solve the following:

$$\int_{-\infty}^0e^x\sin(x)dx=?$$

I can visually see that it will converge and that it should be less than $1$:

$$\int_{-\infty}^0e^x\sin(x)dx<\int_{-\infty}^0e^xdx=1$$

But I am unsure what its exact value is.

Trying to find the definite integral by integrating by parts 4 times only results in $e^x\sin(x)$, which got me nowhere.

How should I evaluate this?

Comment: +1 to this question. You seem genuinely interested in learning :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Integrating by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts) two times you get
$$\begin{align}
\int e^x \cdot \sin x \quad dx & = e^x \cdot \sin x - \int e^x \cdot \cos x \quad dx\\
& = e^x \cdot \sin x - \left( \int e^x \cdot \cos x \quad dx \right)\\
& = e^x \cdot \sin x - \left( e^x\cdot \cos x +  \int e^x \cdot \sin x\quad dx\right)\\
& = e^x \cdot \sin x -  e^x\cdot \cos x -  \int e^x \cdot \sin x\quad dx\\
& = e^x \cdot \left( \sin x - \cos x\right)-  \int e^x \cdot \sin x\quad dx\\
\end{align}$$
hence
$$\int e^x \cdot \sin x \quad dx = e^x \cdot \left( \sin x - \cos x\right)-  \int e^x \cdot \sin x\quad dx\\
\Rightarrow \int e^x \cdot \sin x \quad dx = \frac{e^x \cdot \left( \sin x - \cos x\right)}{2}$$

Finally finding $\int_{-\infty}^0e^x\sin(x)dx$ it's just a matter of substitutions
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^0e^x\sin(x)dx &= \frac{e^x \cdot \left( \sin x - \cos x\right)}{2} \Big|_{-\infty} ^0\\
&= \frac{1 \cdot \left( 0 - 1\right)}{2} - \lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{e^x \cdot \left( \sin x - \cos x\right)}{2}\\
&=-\frac{1}{2} - 0\\
&=-\frac{1}{2}
\end{align}$$

Comment: How did you get there?

Comment: Let $J = \int e^x \sin x \ d x$. Integrate by parts and we find

$$J = e^x(\sin x - \cos x) - J$$

Then solve for $J$. At first it appears the procedure hasn't got us anywhere when in fact we have.

Comment: Oh, that's something I can really understand

Answer (score 5):

$$
\int_{-\infty}^0e^x\sin(x)dx = 
\mbox{Im}\int_{-\infty}^0 e^{x(1+i)}dx
=\mbox{Im}\left.\frac{1}{1+i}e^{x(1+i)}\right|_{-\infty}^0
=\mbox{Im}\frac{1}{1+i}=\mbox{Im}\frac{1-i}{2}=-\frac{1}{2}.
$$

Comment: I am not familiar with that method.  Could you at least tell me what you did and what this method is called?

Comment: Treat the original integral as the imaginary part of another integral, which is much easier to integrate.

Comment: Could you explain how you managed to find this other integral?

Comment: The other integral is just a simple one involving exponential. I added one more step.

Comment: Well, I'm going to mark the other one as answered because it was easier for me.  Thank you for your answer though, I will keep that in mind.  :D

Comment: If I may ask, is there a name for this method?

Comment: I don't think it is a general method for integration, it is more a technique showing that complex variables can simplify the evaluation of certain integrals.

Answer (score 2):

It can easily be done by applying by parts twice:
Let
$$ I=\int e^x \cdot \sin x \quad dx = e^x\sin x-\int e^x\cos x\,dx$$
for the second one apply by parts,
$$\int e^x\cos x\,dx=e^x\cos x+I$$
so, $$I = \frac{1}{2} e^x (\sin x -\cos x)$$

Answer (score 0):

In combination with yhhuang's answer, I think I have a similar explanation:

$$\int e^x\cdot\sin(x)dx=\int e^x\cdot\text{Im}(\cos(x)+i\sin(x))dx$$

$$=\int e^x\cdot\text{Im}(e^{xi})dx$$

$$=\text{Im}\int e^{x(1+i)}dx$$

I found this easier to understand.